# How can I use str_remove() within a list of dataframes using a map function?

Tags: r, purrr, stringr

I have a list of dataframes that all contain a matching ID column.

For example...

```
dat1 = tribble(
    ~id, ~response,
    "id_1", 10,
    "id_2", 15
  )

  dat2 = tribble(
    ~id, ~response,
    "id_3", 20,
    "id_4", 25
  )

example_list <- list(dat1, dat2)

> list(dat1, dat2)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    response
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 id_1        10
2 id_2        15

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    response
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 id_3        20
2 id_4        25
```

How can I map across the dataframes to remove the "id_" prefix for each row on the `id` column using `str_remove()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `purrr::map`, then `str_remove` (or `gsub` or `readr::parse_number`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
example_list %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, id = str_remove(id, "id_")))
  #map(~ .x %>% mutate(id = gsub("id_", "", id)))
  #map(~ mutate(.x, id = parse_number(id)))
```

output

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    response
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 1           10
2 2           15

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  id    response
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 3           20
2 4           25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a `modify_at()` for greater speed. Also, `substring` should be faster than some text match, since you know the length of your prefix already.

Of course, you may want an `as.integer()` to convert this back to to a number, but that is solution independent.

```r
library(purrr)

example_list %>% 
  map(modify_at, "id", substring, 4)

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   id    response
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 1           10
# 2 2           15
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   id    response
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 3           20
# 2 4           25

# to convert to integer
example_list %>% 
    map(modify_at, "id", ~ as.integer(substring(.x, 4)))
```

Running a few options as a benchmark:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  modify_substring = example_list %>% 
    map(modify_at, "id", substring, 4),
  
  mutate_substring = example_list %>% 
    map(~ mutate(.x, id = substring(id, 4))),
  
  mutate_str_remove = example_list %>% 
    map(~ mutate(.x, id = str_remove(id, "id_")))
)
```

You can see that this approach runs substantially quicker.

```r
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq     mean    median       uq        max neval
  modify_substring  302.301  359.9005  442.340  419.6505  459.901   1597.401   100
  mutate_substring 3019.502 3308.6015 4916.405 3540.5505 3847.801 116220.501   100
 mutate_str_remove 4064.801 4568.4010 5355.351 4839.1010 5232.452  10521.701   100
```